# Save attachment with incoming email sender's name or email address

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to add the sender's name of every incoming email to the saved attachment item, by storing into a variable so I can use it later, to return the email to that name or email address.

The code below first creates a counter for every item on a folder and rename the file with the date and the original attachment as follows: "2016-01-29 1026 1 POCreation" - the number 1 before the "POCreation" is the counter.

Then I save the attachment by running a rule in Outlook to run below script - as you might be aware - and save the attachment name by using the objAtt.DisplayName

**So basically I want to get the name of the sender or the email of the sender stored on a variable.** All the forums that I visit, even here, explained that they go to the "MAPI" folder to read all the emails in there but I am thinking that perhaps I can get it straight just like using the .displayname.

I tried to use mailitem.sendername but this throws an error of object not found, I guess is not reading it from the incoming email. I am running this into a module of Outlook.

```
Public Sub pdf(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim FolderPath As String, path As String, count As Integer
FolderPath = "C:\Users\esacahui\Documents\POS\received"

path = FolderPath & "\*.xlsm"

FileName = Dir(path)

Do While FileName <> ""
    count = count + 1
    FileName = Dir()
Loop
' that was the counter, now is the save attachment 

Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
    saveFolder = "C:\Users\esacahui\Documents\POS\received"
Dim dateFormat As String
    dateFormat = Format(itm.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd Hmm")

For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & " " & count & " " & objAtt.DisplayName
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Where in the code exactly do you use the `SenderName` property of the `MailItem` class?

Comment: itm is defined as Outlook.MailItem in your arguments to the Sub. So you need to use itm.SenderName as mentioned in my comments below.

Answer (score 0):

itm.senderEmailAddress will get you the email address of the sender.

Comment: And there is itm.SenderName

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following properties of the MailItem class:

- [SenderEmailAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868262.aspx) - a string that represents the e-mail address of the sender of the Outlook item.
- [SenderName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff869598.aspx) - a string indicating the display name of the sender for the Outlook item.

See [How to: Get the SMTP Address of the Sender of a Mail Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184624.aspx) for more information.