# Save attachments when received. "runtime error:13 Type mismatch"

Tags: vba, download, outlook, attachment

I have several unseen email attachment in email. I would like to download it automatically whenever I receive it from specific sender. I'm using Outlook 2013.

I get:

> runtime error:13 Type mismatch

```vb
Private Sub Application_NewMail()
    
    Dim onamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set onamespace = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    Dim myfol As Outlook.Folder
    Set myfol = onamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    Dim omail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set omail = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Dim atmt As Outlook.attachment
    
    For Each omail In myfol.Items
    
        If omail.SenderEmailAddress = "@gmail.com" Then
        
            For Each atmt In omail.Attachments
                
                atmt.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\raj\Downloads\" & atmt.fileName
                
            Next
        
        Else
        End If
    
    Next
                
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type Mismatch in Loop to scan Outlook Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701705/type-mismatch-in-loop-to-scan-outlook-messages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a [macro rules](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/), when you receive an email from specific sender run a script.

About automatically save attachment, you could refer to this link:

```
Public Sub Save_Attachment(olItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim olAttch As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim sPath As String

    'sPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\"
    sPath = "C:\Temp\"

For Each olAttch In olItem.Attachments
       If olAttch.UnRead = True Then
           If olAttch.SenderEmailAddress = "someone@example.com" Then
               olAttch.SaveAsFile sPath & "\" & olAttch.DisplayName
               olAttch.UnRead = false
           End If
       End If
    Next

    Set olAttch = Nothing
End Sub
```

Reference from:

[Save attachment with incoming email sender's name or email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090714/save-attachment-with-incoming-email-senders-name-or-email-address)